# Magento Payment Information not showing on new orders or transactional emails

Tags: php, magento, payment

Strange issue here, in which I am not sure of what the problem maybe.

When I create new orders through the backend using COD/Purchase Order/Bank Transfer as the payment method, this information is not saved and visible in the payment information block, and as such a result not visible on the transactional emails.

The Payment Information section just displays "Order was placed using GBP"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a bug, that's Magento !

Bank wire informations are shown nowhere expect on the "payment method" selection *before* having placed the order, and in the order confirmation printable doc. 
That sucks, that's it :)

(Magento 1.7.0.0 here)

Comment: Can you explaing in detail?

Comment: Actually there's nothing much to explain, that just hasn't been thought by magento developpers...